# Can you get hyperlinks to work in a published spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I created a Google Sheets, included a link within it (using the "hyperlink" function) and then published the file to the web. It turns out that when you access it from the web, links don't work. Nothing happens.

Comment: Why don't you share a doc with us, so that we can have a look?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra please: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SWdvhNgwKFDBXKWaQ4OQDtQ8XptADOx9x3e2p9KFQ_Q/pubhtml
thanks :)

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra, the link to the "other sheet" isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a spreadsheet with a working example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ai2d5B0yP7tLdGxPYTctVzVzdGF3NXUxeUlVS181MXc&output=html

The formula I use in column C is: =HYPERLINK(+B3;A3)
In column A is the name, in column B is the url
You should not forget to right click in the cells in column C and choose: show links

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I right clicked the cell but don't see a show links option...

Comment: That example works because the entire contents of the cell is the link.    But when I tried having some other text concatenated as well   (eg   C3 = ="test2:  " & hyperlink(+O28, "Fred")   )   the link inside the cell did not work, even before publishing the document.